# Discovery of other subnets from KVM

Tags: networking, security, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM-based VPS with one of the popular providers:

```
# lshw -class system
hostname
    description: Computer
    product: KVM
    vendor: Red Hat
    version: RHEL 6.6.0 PC
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal family=Red Hat Enterprise Linux uuid=XXX
```

Recently, while doing maintenance of the home network, I have noticed that when traffic is being routed via VPN-server running on the instance, quite a few devices around the remote DC on different private subnets are readily accessible: [ping of /16 subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1VyJ.png)

Initially I thought that's some sort of a bug with WinBox, Mikrotik software, but it appeared that services running on those machines do indeed respond: [IDRAC web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GyaK.png)

I believe that shouldn't be possible no matter what arcane stuff client is doing on their VPS instance. Am I missing something?

Comment: Someone has obviously not properly isolated customer networks from each other or from control plane networks. But what is your question about this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I was mildly unsure either it's a bug or feature.

Comment: It sounds like someone at your DC screwed up pretty badly. You should have a chat with them.